# Shading in R normal plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to shade all height beneath a height of 72 inches. With this code it outputs incorrect shading. How do you code this to shade it perfectly?

```
mean = 69.1
sd = 2.9
x <- seq(-3.5,3.5,length=100)*sd + mean
y <- dnorm(x,mean,sd)
plot(x, y, type="l")
polygon(c(x[x<=72], min(x), 72), c(y[x<=72], 0, 0), col="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
polygon(c(x[x<=72], 72, min(x)), 
        c(y[x<=72], 0,  0), col="red")
```

(I think you just had your points swapped. We can look at `x[x<=72]` and `y[x<=72]` to see that they trace the points rightward toward the right edge of the curve. We still need to get down to (72, 0) before we come back to the origin.)

[image]

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer me! have a great day!